# Dataset From Bigquery To Datastudio

Tags: firebase, google-bigquery, looker-studio

I connect my Firebase project to BigQuery. Then, I connected the BigQuery to DataStudio to create a dynamic dashboard.

The default DataStudio collector does not work. It gives me back an error. Going to analyze the BigQuery logs I get this:

QUERY:

```
SELECT t0.device.browser, t0.device.browser_version, 
t0.device.web_info.browser, t0.device.web_info.browser_version 
FROM  my_dataset.my_table AS t0 LIMIT 100;
```

RETURN:

```
 jobStatus: {
  additionalErrors: [
   0: {
    code:  11          
    message:  "Duplicate column names in the result are not supported. Found duplicate(s): browser, browser_version"          
   }
  ]
  error: {
   code:  11         
   message:  "Duplicate column names in the result are not supported. Found duplicate(s): browser, browser_version"         
  }
  state:  "DONE"        
 }
}
```

Not being able to change the scheme I have no way to fix this?

Is there any way to report this to google?

Answer (score 1):

The duplicated columns are shown here:

For browser version:

t0.device.web_info.**browser_version**

t0.device.**browser_version**

For browser:

t0.device.**browser**

t0.device.web_info.**browser**

They might look different and / or are from different sources or elements but the column names are the same, which is causing issues here.

If you can't change the schema, I recommend you to use *aliases* for each column like:

```
SELECT 
  t0.device.browser AS device_browser, 
  t0.device.browser_version AS device_browser_version, 
  t0.device.web_info.browser AS web_browser, 
  t0.device.web_info.browser_version AS web_browser_version
FROM  my_dataset.my_table AS t0 LIMIT 100;
```

I hope this is helpful!